# Find and alter links with js in a text

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom, hyperlink

I have a text that must be send as an email. But to give the mail its layout we need to add some style.
What we must do is the following:
1 find in a text one or more links with this format

```
<a href="RANDOM URL HERE">RANDOM TEXT</a>
```

2 change the links into this format:

```
<a href="RANDOM URL HERE" style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;"><span style="color: #FFFFFF;">RANDOM TEXT</span></a>
```

I have no idea how i can best do this, with regex or with DOM,...

Many thanks!

Comment: Why insert a span, when you already modify the style in `a` tag?

Comment: because some mail clients only look at the '<span>' tag, and some only look at the style in the '<a>' tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should consider *never* using regex for working with HTML/XML markup. You can read the reason here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1249581 :)

Then, in order to answer the question you should do the following:

```
var div = document.createElement("div"),
    links;

div.innerHTML = textOfYourEmail;
links = div.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = links.length; i--;) {
    var link = links[i],
        span = document.createElement("span");

    link.style.textDecoration = "none";
    link.style.color = "#fff";
    span.style.color = "#fff";

    while (link.firstChild) {
        span.appendChild(link.firstChild);
    }
    link.appendChild(span);
}

textOfYourEmail = div.innerHTML;
```

It uses embedded methods for DOM manipulation. It is fast and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to do that is to create a css class and add it to your links. You do not need to add span tags! Using the DOM is the best way.

Comment: But it is for a text that will be used as an email, and email does not use css classes, it has to be inline